# Getting the sound of really good micro bubbles

Tags: steamed-milk

I have heard that the perfect sound while steaming milk should sound like paper ripping, but I have seen a lot more talented people making a decent coffee with good micro bubbles without that sound.

Is there a "perfect sound" to know that you are getting the best micro bubbles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sound it's not a very good "measure stick" for steaming. That is because it would depend on the steaming wand (how many steam holes has, how much steam the machine produces, etc), the pitcher (the form of it affects in how the milk moves inside), the milk (yes, whole-milk vs almond are very different), etc...

So, I suggest to you that don't focus on other's people *steaming sound*, but instead on theirs technique. Of course there are some sounds that indicates some process (the first sound it's very loud, until the milk circulates enough), but there aren't a sufficient parameters (on my POV).

You can check [this](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/3409/825) related answer. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: thank you for you answer but i hope if some one has another opinion please send a post.